# group cohomology of permutation groups

Tags: algebraic-topology, finite-groups, permutations, homology-cohomology, group-cohomology

Let $\Sigma_k$ be the permutation group of order $k$. Let $F$ be a field. What is the cohomology
$$
H^*(\Sigma_k;F)=H^*(K(\Sigma_k,1);F)=H^*(B\Sigma_k;F)?
$$

For $F=\mathbb{Z}/p\mathbb{Z}$ for prime $p\leq k$?

Comment: See, for example, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/180637/cohomology-of-symmetric-groups.